# Python search for multiple strings in a folder full of text files, copy the rows and 50 rows below it to another file

Tags: python, string, search

I have a folder called 'inputs' that is full of text files that end in either a '.measbu' or '.info' extension (for example, c.171203fl.so.power.simu.measbu and s.170210.so.power.info)

The .measbu text files each contain seven maps (among other data).  The maps look like this (Stack Overflow limits the number of characters I can paste from each map so I can only show three of them):

```
1


 channel averaged  cell avg  fast fluxes   core 171203fl  k-eff: 1.052447 scale = 1e+14

                                    reactor power = 100.0 mw

                     Triad3PC-Power v1.1.1.1   ld=2007-02-01

 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
          burnup type: measbu     lattice split: on     discontinuity factors: normal
 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

          y   z   a   b   c   d    e   f   g   h   j   k   l   m   n   o   p   q   r   s   t 

 34                                             0.019                                            34
 33                                 0.042   0.054   0.043   0.015                                33
 32                             0.052   0.115   0.079   0.064   0.009                            32
 31                        0.035    0.174   0.158   0.128   0.047   0.003                        31
 30                    0.034    0.170   0.269   0.129   0.160   0.012   0.002                    30
 29                0.020   0.118    0.427   0.377   0.329   0.068   0.004   0.003                29
 28                    0.102    0.331   0.454   0.140   0.324   0.015   0.007                    28
 27                0.053   0.263    0.385   0.301   0.111   0.082   0.009   0.016                27
 26            0.017   0.151    0.509   0.194   0.102   0.100   0.039   0.027   0.019            26
 25        0.006   0.051   0.397    0.379   0.134   0.099   0.203   0.031   0.052   0.011        25
 24            0.024   0.086    0.232   0.288   0.292   0.135   0.051   0.136   0.050            24
 23        0.016   0.029   0.140    0.160   0.203   0.281   0.103   0.088   0.108   0.036        23
 22            0.047   0.096    0.178   0.341   0.402   0.347   0.079   0.249   0.118            22
 21        0.045   0.085   0.487    0.219   0.484   0.226   0.183   0.294   0.362   0.070        21
 20    0.017   0.132   0.215    0.683   0.192   0.470   0.482   0.197   0.173   0.143   0.032    20
 19        0.087   0.374   0.442    0.493   0.191   0.206   0.511   0.358   0.188   0.142        19
 18    0.030   0.204   0.532    0.504   0.147   0.193   0.212   0.478   0.248   0.424   0.054    18
 17        0.104   0.365   0.324    0.144   0.361   0.378   0.245   0.717   0.469   0.185        17
 16    0.031   0.205   0.185    0.104   0.135   0.238   0.217   0.577   0.466   0.302   0.061    16
 15        0.090   0.357   0.096    0.090   0.458   0.269   0.513   0.569   0.203   0.173        15
 14    0.023   0.137   0.148    0.097   0.192   0.567   0.529   0.232   0.301   0.343   0.052    14
 13        0.053   0.125   0.260    0.332   0.577   0.558   0.351   0.127   0.121   0.134        13
 12    0.012   0.054   0.375    0.116   0.204   0.305   0.264   0.079   0.100   0.122   0.035    12
 11        0.039   0.127   0.251    0.107   0.472   0.524   0.126   0.067   0.147   0.109        11
 10            0.120   0.189    0.056   0.249   0.212   0.420   0.051   0.282   0.311            10
  9        0.044   0.383   0.156    0.063   0.182   0.187   0.116   0.135   0.381   0.096         9
  8            0.146   0.449    0.113   0.104   0.391   0.102   0.189   0.173   0.156             8
  7        0.027   0.227   0.461    0.144   0.292   0.098   0.305   0.558   0.099   0.032         7
  6            0.066   0.231    0.436   0.182   0.125   0.138   0.593   0.170   0.046             6
  5                0.097   0.128    0.483   0.177   0.154   0.242   0.553   0.064                 5
  4                    0.080    0.132   0.501   0.153   0.511   0.218   0.146                     4
  3                0.021   0.046    0.160   0.422   0.475   0.455   0.109   0.030                 3
  2                    0.020    0.054   0.231   0.162   0.208   0.098   0.036                     2
  1                        0.014    0.084   0.167   0.161   0.137   0.026                         1
  0                             0.022   0.091   0.092   0.086   0.034                             0
 -1                                 0.025   0.055   0.052   0.031                                -1
 -2                                             0.021                                            -2

          y   z   a   b   c   d    e   f   g   h   j   k   l   m   n   o   p   q   r   s   t 

                                         19-DEC-17  10:56:31
1


 channel averaged  cell avg  thermal fluxes    core 171203fl  k-eff: 1.052scale = 1e+14

                                    reactor power = 100.0 mw

                     Triad3PC-Power v1.1.1.1   ld=2007-02-01

 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
          burnup type: measbu     lattice split: on     discontinuity factors: normal
 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

          y   z   a   b   c   d    e   f   g   h   j   k   l   m   n   o   p   q   r   s   t 

 34                                              0.11                                            34
 33                                  0.15    0.27    0.27    0.14                                33
 32                              0.22    0.42    0.53    0.40    0.19                            32
 31                         0.23     0.57    0.71    0.70    0.52    0.20                        31
 30                     0.21     0.71    0.85    1.05    0.82    0.58    0.18                    30
 29                 0.13    0.71     0.99    1.03    1.05    0.97    0.56    0.14                29
 28                     0.60     1.19    1.15    1.43    1.15    0.98    0.51                    28
 27                 0.44    1.12     1.41    1.21    1.60    1.37    0.93    0.42                27
 26             0.25    0.98     1.48    1.44    1.67    1.67    1.34    0.86    0.28            26
 25         0.11    0.79    1.40     1.65    1.67    1.83    1.53    1.30    0.74    0.13        25
 24             0.53    1.40     1.91    1.70    1.68    1.86    1.70    1.13    0.58            24
 23         0.23    1.10    1.89     2.11    1.73    1.80    1.97    1.67    1.12    0.32        23
 22             0.73    1.68     2.10    2.00    1.85    1.87    2.04    1.46    0.87            22
 21         0.36    1.32    1.73     2.26    2.05    1.95    2.25    1.79    1.28    0.56        21
 20     0.10    0.82    1.80     1.34    2.53    2.14    2.05    2.23    1.89    1.21    0.19    20
 19         0.45    1.18    1.86     2.13    2.64    2.43    2.06    1.89    1.74    0.70        19
 18     0.15    0.80    1.46     2.02    2.68    2.65    2.42    1.96    1.92    1.14    0.24    18
 17         0.48    1.02    1.87     2.54    2.48    2.34    2.11    1.29    1.49    0.73        17
 16     0.16    0.81    1.47     2.33    2.65    2.64    2.47    1.98    1.70    1.17    0.26    16
 15         0.50    1.13    1.95     2.43    2.37    2.40    2.16    1.90    1.49    0.71        15
 14     0.16    0.92    1.72     2.16    2.42    2.21    2.14    2.44    1.82    1.07    0.24    14
 13         0.52    1.44    1.82     1.97    2.05    2.08    2.21    2.30    1.64    0.69        13
 12     0.12    0.99    1.57     2.11    1.94    2.06    2.04    2.42    2.03    1.22    0.19    12
 11         0.43    1.43    1.86     2.13    1.85    1.97    2.32    2.27    1.61    0.58        11
 10             0.81    1.78     2.17    1.89    2.18    1.92    2.37    1.79    0.92            10
  9         0.25    1.07    2.01     2.18    1.84    2.18    2.22    2.24    1.28    0.38         9
  8             0.56    1.35     2.17    2.12    1.91    1.79    2.31    1.87    0.76             8
  7         0.11    0.82    1.56     2.18    1.94    2.16    2.00    1.81    1.23    0.17         7
  6             0.27    1.09     1.73    2.14    2.21    2.13    1.88    1.56    0.45             6
  5                 0.48    1.40     1.69    2.11    2.17    2.14    1.50    0.77                 5
  4                     0.71     1.53    1.61    2.05    1.76    1.84    0.98                     4
  3                 0.16    0.84     1.46    1.50    1.58    1.48    1.18    0.27                 3
  2                     0.25     0.91    1.19    1.51    1.48    1.16    0.37                     2
  1                         0.27     0.78    1.01    1.12    0.94    0.43                         1
  0                              0.28    0.59    0.78    0.72    0.36                             0
 -1                                  0.21    0.39    0.42    0.25                                -1
 -2                                              0.17                                            -2

          y   z   a   b   c   d    e   f   g   h   j   k   l   m   n   o   p   q   r   s   t 

                                         19-DEC-17  10:56:31
1


 channel averaged  boundary  fast fluxes   core 171203fl  k-eff: 1.052447 scale = 1e+14

                                    reactor power = 100.0 mw

                     Triad3PC-Power v1.1.1.1   ld=2007-02-01

 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
          burnup type: measbu     lattice split: on     discontinuity factors: normal
 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

          y   z   a   b   c   d    e   f   g   h   j   k   l   m   n   o   p   q   r   s   t 

 34                                             0.019                                            34
 33                                 0.042   0.054   0.043   0.015                                33
 32                             0.052   0.115   0.079   0.064   0.009                            32
 31                        0.035    0.174   0.158   0.128   0.047   0.003                        31
 30                    0.034    0.170   0.269   0.147   0.161   0.013   0.002                    30
 29                0.020   0.118    0.313   0.277   0.240   0.078   0.004   0.003                29
 28                    0.102    0.274   0.336   0.160   0.236   0.018   0.007                    28
 27                0.053   0.224    0.327   0.241   0.127   0.094   0.010   0.016                27
 26            0.017   0.151    0.375   0.222   0.117   0.116   0.045   0.030   0.019            26
 25        0.006   0.051   0.294    0.308   0.154   0.113   0.164   0.036   0.052   0.011        25
 24            0.024   0.099    0.234   0.243   0.238   0.143   0.058   0.118   0.050            24
 23        0.016   0.034   0.160    0.184   0.231   0.247   0.117   0.101   0.125   0.036        23
 22            0.047   0.110    0.203   0.284   0.334   0.281   0.091   0.213   0.118            22
 21        0.045   0.097   0.361    0.250   0.375   0.260   0.209   0.240   0.262   0.070        21
 20    0.017   0.132   0.246    0.520   0.219   0.365   0.370   0.225   0.198   0.163   0.032    20
 19        0.087   0.284   0.379    0.388   0.220   0.234   0.387   0.317   0.215   0.142        19
 18    0.030   0.204   0.383    0.399   0.168   0.220   0.242   0.404   0.283   0.304   0.054    18
 17        0.104   0.297   0.280    0.165   0.298   0.301   0.282   0.552   0.348   0.185        17
 16    0.031   0.205   0.212    0.119   0.154   0.271   0.248   0.459   0.387   0.265   0.061    16
 15        0.090   0.261   0.111    0.103   0.380   0.300   0.403   0.439   0.232   0.173        15
 14    0.023   0.137   0.169    0.107   0.219   0.443   0.413   0.265   0.259   0.248   0.052    14
 13        0.053   0.143   0.221    0.256   0.437   0.435   0.302   0.146   0.135   0.134        13
 12    0.012   0.062   0.281    0.123   0.234   0.349   0.304   0.091   0.114   0.140   0.035    12
 11        0.039   0.146   0.219    0.122   0.358   0.397   0.143   0.077   0.164   0.109        11
 10            0.121   0.216    0.064   0.215   0.244   0.321   0.058   0.231   0.228            10
  9        0.044   0.278   0.178    0.072   0.208   0.214   0.133   0.154   0.280   0.096         9
  8            0.146   0.335    0.129   0.119   0.297   0.129   0.216   0.197   0.156             8
  7        0.027   0.227   0.341    0.165   0.242   0.113   0.258   0.410   0.113   0.032         7
  6            0.066   0.231    0.329   0.207   0.142   0.158   0.439   0.195   0.046             6
  5                0.097   0.147    0.358   0.202   0.175   0.276   0.396   0.064                 5
  4                    0.080    0.152   0.369   0.175   0.379   0.249   0.146                     4
  3                0.021   0.046    0.184   0.316   0.345   0.331   0.124   0.030                 3
  2                    0.020    0.054   0.231   0.185   0.239   0.112   0.036                     2
  1                        0.014    0.084   0.167   0.161   0.137   0.026                         1
  0                             0.022   0.091   0.092   0.086   0.034                             0
 -1                                 0.025   0.055   0.052   0.031                                -1
 -2                                             0.021                                            -2

          y   z   a   b   c   d    e   f   g   h   j   k   l   m   n   o   p   q   r   s   t 

                                         19-DEC-17  10:56:31
```

Each .info file contains three maps (and other data that I don't need).  The three maps look like this:

```
1


 scan 170210 fission power at tpd 223207.8   total power  112.210

                     Triad3PC-ScanPower v1.1.1.1   ld=2007-03-27

 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
          burnup type: measbu     lattice split: on     discontinuity factors: normal
 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

          y   z   a   b   c   d    e   f   g   h   j   k   l   m   n   o   p   q   r   s   t 

 34                                               ...                                            34
 33                                   ...     ...     ...     ...                                33
 32                               ...     ...     ...     ...     ...                            32
 31                          ...      ...     ...     ...     ...     ...                        31
 30                      ...      ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...                    30
 29                  ...     ...    1.278   1.450   1.306     ...     ...     ...                29
 28                      ...    0.582   1.391     ...   1.353     ...     ...                    28
 27                  ...   0.597    1.071     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...                27
 26              ...     ...    1.533     ...     ...   0.670     ...     ...     ...            26
 25          ...     ...   1.372    1.019     ...     ...   0.735     ...     ...     ...        25
 24              ...     ...      ...   0.839   0.761     ...     ...   0.725     ...            24
 23          ...     ...     ...      ...     ...   0.966     ...     ...   1.258     ...        23
 22              ...     ...      ...   0.872   1.081   1.050     ...   0.629     ...            22
 21          ...     ...   1.667      ...   1.068     ...     ...   1.058   1.479     ...        21
 20      ...     ...     ...    2.327     ...   1.520   1.811     ...     ...     ...     ...    20
 19          ...   1.385   0.966    1.557   1.282     ...   1.497   0.981     ...     ...        19
 18      ...     ...   1.571    1.059     ...     ...   1.081   1.467     ...   1.298     ...    18
 17          ...   0.777   1.378      ...   1.553   1.694     ...   2.371   1.523     ...        17
 16      ...     ...     ...      ...     ...     ...     ...   1.659   1.237     ...     ...    16
 15          ...   1.342     ...    1.250   1.524     ...   0.969   0.961     ...     ...        15
 14      ...     ...     ...      ...     ...   1.783   1.592     ...   0.888   1.088     ...    14
 13          ...     ...   1.102    1.581   1.778   1.629   1.297     ...   0.149     ...        13
 12      ...     ...   1.596      ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...    12
 11          ...     ...   1.323      ...   1.563   1.451     ...     ...   0.156     ...        11
 10              ...     ...      ...   1.550     ...   0.959     ...   0.959   0.509            10
  9          ...   1.297     ...    1.541     ...     ...     ...     ...   0.945     ...         9
  8              ...   1.622      ...     ...   0.851     ...     ...     ...     ...             8
  7          ...     ...   1.535      ...   1.060     ...   0.775   1.396     ...     ...         7
  6              ...     ...    1.595     ...     ...     ...   1.364     ...     ...             6
  5                  ...     ...    1.490   1.038     ...     ...     ...     ...                 5
  4                      ...      ...   1.546     ...   1.280     ...     ...                     4
  3                  ...     ...      ...   1.490   1.488   1.097     ...     ...                 3
  2                      ...      ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...                     2
  1                          ...      ...     ...     ...     ...     ...                         1
  0                               ...     ...     ...     ...     ...                             0
 -1                                   ...     ...     ...     ...                                -1
 -2                                               ...                                            -2

          y   z   a   b   c   d    e   f   g   h   j   k   l   m   n   o   p   q   r   s   t 

                                         13-FEB-17  10:04:39
1


 scan 170210 power-to-coolant at tpd 223207.8   total power  104.210

                     Triad3PC-ScanPower v1.1.1.1   ld=2007-03-27

 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
          burnup type: measbu     lattice split: on     discontinuity factors: normal
 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

          y   z   a   b   c   d    e   f   g   h   j   k   l   m   n   o   p   q   r   s   t 

 34                                               ...                                            34
 33                                   ...     ...     ...     ...                                33
 32                               ...     ...     ...     ...     ...                            32
 31                          ...      ...     ...     ...     ...     ...                        31
 30                      ...      ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...                    30
 29                  ...     ...    1.184   1.343   1.210     ...     ...     ...                29
 28                      ...    0.539   1.288     ...   1.254     ...     ...                    28
 27                  ...   0.553    0.992     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...                27
 26              ...     ...    1.420     ...     ...   0.621     ...     ...     ...            26
 25          ...     ...   1.271    0.944     ...     ...   0.681     ...     ...     ...        25
 24              ...     ...      ...   0.777   0.705     ...     ...   0.671     ...            24
 23          ...     ...     ...      ...     ...   0.895     ...     ...   1.165     ...        23
 22              ...     ...      ...   0.807   1.002   0.972     ...   0.583     ...            22
 21          ...     ...   1.544      ...   0.989     ...     ...   0.980   1.370     ...        21
 20      ...     ...     ...    2.234     ...   1.408   1.677     ...     ...     ...     ...    20
 19          ...   1.283   0.895    1.443   1.187     ...   1.387   0.909     ...     ...        19
 18      ...     ...   1.455    0.981     ...     ...   1.001   1.359     ...   1.203     ...    18
 17          ...   0.766   1.277      ...   1.438   1.570     ...   2.276   1.410     ...        17
 16      ...     ...     ...      ...     ...     ...     ...   1.537   1.146     ...     ...    16
 15          ...   1.243     ...    1.158   1.411     ...   0.898   0.890     ...     ...        15
 14      ...     ...     ...      ...     ...   1.652   1.475     ...   0.822   1.007     ...    14
 13          ...     ...   1.021    1.464   1.647   1.509   1.201     ...   0.138     ...        13
 12      ...     ...   1.478      ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...    12
 11          ...     ...   1.225      ...   1.448   1.344     ...     ...   0.145     ...        11
 10              ...     ...      ...   1.435     ...   0.889     ...   0.889   0.472            10
  9          ...   1.201     ...    1.428     ...     ...     ...     ...   0.875     ...         9
  8              ...   1.503      ...     ...   0.788     ...     ...     ...     ...             8
  7          ...     ...   1.422      ...   0.982     ...   0.718   1.293     ...     ...         7
  6              ...     ...    1.477     ...     ...     ...   1.263     ...     ...             6
  5                  ...     ...    1.381   1.023     ...     ...     ...     ...                 5
  4                      ...      ...   1.433     ...   1.185     ...     ...                     4
  3                  ...     ...      ...   1.381   1.378   1.016     ...     ...                 3
  2                      ...      ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...                     2
  1                          ...      ...     ...     ...     ...     ...                         1
  0                               ...     ...     ...     ...     ...                             0
 -1                                   ...     ...     ...     ...                                -1
 -2                                               ...                                            -2

          y   z   a   b   c   d    e   f   g   h   j   k   l   m   n   o   p   q   r   s   t 

                                         13-FEB-17  10:04:39
1


 scan 170210 fission power factor map at tpd 223207.8   total power  100.000

                     Triad3PC-ScanPower v1.1.1.1   ld=2007-03-27

 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
          burnup type: measbu     lattice split: on     discontinuity factors: normal
 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

          y   z   a   b   c   d    e   f   g   h   j   k   l   m   n   o   p   q   r   s   t 

 34                                               ...                                            34
 33                                   ...     ...     ...     ...                                33
 32                               ...     ...     ...     ...     ...                            32
 31                          ...      ...     ...     ...     ...     ...                        31
 30                      ...      ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...                    30
 29                  ...     ...    1.139   1.292   1.164     ...     ...     ...                29
 28                      ...    0.518   1.239     ...   1.206     ...     ...                    28
 27                  ...   0.532    0.954     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...                27
 26              ...     ...    1.366     ...     ...   0.597     ...     ...     ...            26
 25          ...     ...   1.223    0.908     ...     ...   0.655     ...     ...     ...        25
 24              ...     ...      ...   0.748   0.678     ...     ...   0.646     ...            24
 23          ...     ...     ...      ...     ...   0.861     ...     ...   1.121     ...        23
 22              ...     ...      ...   0.777   0.964   0.935     ...   0.560     ...            22
 21          ...     ...   1.485      ...   0.952     ...     ...   0.943   1.318     ...        21
 20      ...     ...     ...    2.074     ...   1.355   1.614     ...     ...     ...     ...    20
 19          ...   1.234   0.861    1.388   1.142     ...   1.334   0.874     ...     ...        19
 18      ...     ...   1.400    0.944     ...     ...   0.963   1.307     ...   1.157     ...    18
 17          ...   0.692   1.228      ...   1.384   1.510     ...   2.113   1.357     ...        17
 16      ...     ...     ...      ...     ...     ...     ...   1.478   1.102     ...     ...    16
 15          ...   1.196     ...    1.114   1.358     ...   0.864   0.856     ...     ...        15
 14      ...     ...     ...      ...     ...   1.589   1.419     ...   0.791   0.969     ...    14
 13          ...     ...   0.982    1.409   1.584   1.452   1.155     ...   0.133     ...        13
 12      ...     ...   1.422      ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...    12
 11          ...     ...   1.179      ...   1.393   1.293     ...     ...   0.139     ...        11
 10              ...     ...      ...   1.381     ...   0.855     ...   0.855   0.454            10
  9          ...   1.156     ...    1.373     ...     ...     ...     ...   0.842     ...         9
  8              ...   1.445      ...     ...   0.758     ...     ...     ...     ...             8
  7          ...     ...   1.368      ...   0.944     ...   0.691   1.244     ...     ...         7
  6              ...     ...    1.421     ...     ...     ...   1.216     ...     ...             6
  5                  ...     ...    1.328   0.925     ...     ...     ...     ...                 5
  4                      ...      ...   1.378     ...   1.140     ...     ...                     4
  3                  ...     ...      ...   1.328   1.326   0.978     ...     ...                 3
  2                      ...      ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...                     2
  1                          ...      ...     ...     ...     ...     ...                         1
  0                               ...     ...     ...     ...     ...                             0
 -1                                   ...     ...     ...     ...                                -1
 -2                                               ...                                            -2

          y   z   a   b   c   d    e   f   g   h   j   k   l   m   n   o   p   q   r   s   t 

                                         13-FEB-17  10:04:39
```

I would like Python to go through each .measbu and .info file in the 'inputs' folder and extract all the maps and write them to a separate file called 'maps.txt'.  Just the maps and their respective headers.  I thought about searching on 'channel' and 'total power', since those words/phrases appear above each map ('channel' in the .measbu files, 'total power' in the .info files) and then copying that line along with the 50 rows below, since each map is around 50 rows long.

So far for code I have:

```
import os

for filename in os.listdir('inputs'):
    fn = 'inputs/'+filename
    for line in open(fn, 'r'):
        line.find('channel' or 'total power')
        open('maps.txt', 'w').write(line)
```

But it just writes the date "13-FEB-17  10:04:39" to maps.txt and that's it, and I'm not sure how to get it to copy and paste the 50 lines below each find of 'channel' or 'total power'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason there is only one line in the file is that every time you open the `maps.txt` file in `w` mode, you are erasing it's previous contents and writing a single line in in the document.  What you should do instead is open the `maps.txt` outside of your for loop so it remains open while you iterate through each of directory files, and append the each of the matching files contents to the end of the `maps.txt` file.

For example:

```
import os

dirname = 'inputs'

def check_extension(fn):
    ext = os.path.splitext(fn)[1]
    if ext == ".measbu":
        return "channel"
    elif ext == ".info":
        return "total power"
    return ""

def search_file(term, outfile, infile):
    map_found = False
    count = 0
    for line in infile:
        if map_found:
            outfile.write(line)
            count += 1
        else:
            if term in line:
                map_found = True
                outfile.write(line)
                count += 1
        if count == 50:
            outfile.write("\n\n")
            map_found = False
            count = 0

with open('maps.txt', 'w', encoding='utf8') as outfile:
    for filename in os.listdir(dirname):
        fn = os.path.join(dirname, filename)
        term = check_extension(fn)
        if not term:
            continue
        with open(fn, 'r', encoding="utf8") as infile:                
            search_file(term, outfile, infile)
```

Additional notes:

- `line.find('channel' or 'total power')` is literally doing nothing.
  The expression `'channel' or 'total power'` will always evaluate to `channel`, and `line.find('channel')` doesn't help you either because you are not checking the return value against anything.
- as mentioned before opening a document in `'w'` mode erases whatever that document previously contained.
- It's good practice to use `with` statements for file handling and to explicitly specify the encoding.
- `os.path.joins` is a much safer and easy way to join path parts.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Your code doesn't seem to produce any output though.  The maps.txt file is empty.

Comment: that means that none of your files have channel or total power in the first line of text in the file. @JoeBlough  do the files contain more information than just the maps you are trying to copy in your examples?

Comment: @JoeBlough  See edit to answer... it should work no matter where the text is located on the page

Comment: Yes, the input .measbu and .info files contain more than just the maps.  They contain other information as well, just nothing with the label 'channel' or 'total power' above them.  Sorry, I wasn't able to paste the entire input file above, as Stack Overflow limits the number of characters I can post.

I tried your new code, but the maps.txt file is still coming back empty.

Comment: @JoeBlough  Do you know how to use a debugger?   It is likely empty because it isn't searching for the files in the correct directory.

Comment: Yes, running with the PyCharm debugger it seems to see the files in the inputs directory.  I set up a breakpoint at 'fn = os.path.join(dirname, filename)' and ran the debugger.  It lists 'inputs' as the  directory and 'c.171203fl.so.power.simu.measbu' as the input filename.

Comment: There was a bug in the code. try it again @JoeBlough

Comment: Thanks, it seems to populate the maps.txt file now; however it's only grabbing the first map from each input file.  The .measbu file contains seven maps total and the .info file contains three.  I added in a few extra maps in my original post above (SO limits the number of characters I can paste in) to give a better picture of what the .measbu input file looks like.

Changing the 'break' statement in your code to 'continue' allows the code to extract all three maps from .info, but it extracts everything from .measbu, including other data that I don't need.